# How to show 3 values on the X axis instead of 1?

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have a bar chart which shows a histogram of weight vs count.  The x axis is the weight and the y axis is the count of how many weights fell within that weight range.

I would like to also display the percent of each weight range which would be the weight ranges count/totalcount and show the numeric value of the count next to each weight on the x axis.

So an example of the x axis followed by the y axis should look like this

weight percent count | count

1.000 3.013% 512 | 512

I was able to achieve this by combining the weight, percent and count into one string and then setting the data row of a datatable = to the entire string instead of just the count. However I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this by placing each data value into its very own column, so when I export it into excel instead of a chart it will have its own column for each value instead of one concatenated column of 3 values.

Comment: Maybe I could just check if export to excel is selected rather than chart and then dynamically build my datatable to include a column for each value or one concatenated column depending on what they select.

Answer (score 0):

I could just check if export to excel is selected rather than chart and then dynamically build my data table to include a column for each value or one column with a concatenated value for each row depending on what they select. However I still believe there's a better option that I have not figured out.